# Disable highlighting "info" warnings on flycheck

Tags: flycheck

I'm using flycheck with pylint3 (emacs 24.5) and it creates lots of "info" errors (for things like violating whitespace and capitalization conventions). I know I can disable them on a per-error basis by editing `.pylintrc`, but I'd rather just disable all info errors.

I can customize the flycheck group which has the settings `Flycheck Error List Minimum Level` and `Flycheck Navigation Minimum Level`, which let you disable "info" in the error list and when jumping between errors, respectively. Is there an equivalent setting for controlling which errors are highlighted in the buffer?

(I was thinking that I could change the face of "info" errors to be the normal face, but that would still have some artifacts of flycheck, like displaying the warning in the echo area. If there isn't a "proper" way to disable info, this may be the next-best option.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable all info messages (or any class of messages) in your `.pylintrc`.

```
disable=I
```

Read the output of `pylint --generate-rcfile` for more.

Also, you can put a magic pylint comment in your python file:

```
# pylint: disable=I
```

That will disable info messages for all lines after the comment (you can be much more fine grained too, see [this example](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html)).

Personally, I do `disable=C,R,locally-disabled` in the commandline/rcfile and locally disable other messages with comments.

Comment: Thanks! pylint's `I` is different than flycheck's "info", but your tip about `disable=C,R` (Convention, Refactor) is exactly what I was looking for.